# Is there a way to display an image without importing it?

Tags: html, reactjs

I need to display an image in reactJs project, but I cannot do it witout import the image, what can I do if I cannot import it, like whenever I get its src from server?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are getting a url to an image from your server.

You can use the url to the image in the img srs attribute like this `<img src={urlToImage}/>`

Hope this helps.